# No Printers are installed issue with crystal report PrintToPrinter

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports-2010

I had recently upgraded the Crystal report runtime version from 13.0.1 to 13.0.8 to use the new feature of HTML interpretation of text.

I have the logic of printing crystal report as part of a WCF Service. 
But we are now facing issues while we try to Print the report directly on a network printer using report.PrintToPrinter method saying printer not installed even though it was still installed and working.

when i tried to execute report.ExportToDisk method its sucesfully exporting it as a pdf file on to hard drive with new version 13.0.8

But when rolled back to an older version on CR runtime it started working fine.

Any clues on wat exactly could have caused the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In the application pool, set

> Process Model Load User Profile:  True

To avoid having the domain account or the user that setup the printers logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where a call to PrintToPrinter was working in development but failing in other environments. After tremendous heartache, I discovered that changing the PrintToPrinter call solved the problem. Hopefully this info will help others in the future.

This post from SAP forums lead me in the right direction:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12380707/no-printers-are-installed---printtoprinter-problem.html

Changing from this:

```
crystalReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "\\\\print_server\\printer";
crystalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

to this:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printersettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
printersettings.PrinterName = PrinterToUse;
printersettings.Copies = 1;
printersettings.Collate = false;
Report.PrintToPrinter(printersettings, new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(), false);
```